# displaying array content followed by a string in PHP

Tags: php

Here is a concise of my code structure. What I need to do is print the values of the check boxes (only if those are checked by the user) along with a string attached as a message. In essence the message should be like 'Remove following? 10,20,30'

With my coding I get something like `Delete following?Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 35 )`

can someone help me solve this. Many thanks. (Note: Not all the proper code is mentioned that should come under `<html></html>` and presented what is relevant for understanding (As I believe sufficient)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "Remove following?";
print_r ($_POST['del']);
}
?>

<html>
<form>
// inside html in a dynamically created table I have the following
<?php
echo "<td class='tbldecor1'><input type='checkbox' name='del[]' value='$cxVal'></td>";
echo "<td class='tbldecor2' style='text-align:center'>".trim($rec["firstrow"])."</td>";
<?
<div><input type="submit" name="deleterec" id="deleterec" value="Delete"></div>
</form>
</html>
```

**EDIT** : Also I'm thinking, if I'm to use a loop for printing how do I replace 1,2,3,4,5 values by check box values that a user picks? The loop I'm thinking would be as follows;

```
 <?php 
 $a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); 
 foreach ($a as $b) 
 { 
 print $b . " "; 
 } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the help of [implode](http://php.net/implode) :

```
$vals = $_POST['del'];
echo "Remove following? " . implode( ", ", $vals );
```

**UPDATE** (after @Waleed Khan's warning about HTML injection):

```
// Make sure everything is a number (non-numeric will be replaced with boolean falses)
$vals = filter_var_array( $_POST['del'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ); 
// Remove all boolean falses
$vals = array_filter( $vals );
// String output
$valString = implode( ", ", $vals );
echo "Remove following? {$valString}";
```

Comment: Careful about accidental HTML injection: use `htmlspecialchars` or something.

Comment: @Waleed Khan - Can u show me how to use htmlspecialchars in this situation? Many thanks. ($vals = response generate from hitting a submit button) thanks again

Comment: @StackOne Read the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @Waleed Khan - thanks for this, but my concern was do I need to use full entity translation mechanism even when I'm getting a posted value from button as well?

Comment: As you seem to be working with numbers only, you could validate/sanitize your values with [filter_var_array()](http://php.net/filter_var_array) - I'll update my answer after having finished this comment.

Comment: @jeromegamez I used $resultW = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE * FROM newchk WHERE sbstart='$vals' AND dist_chk='$distUsr'"); and get the Notice: Array to string conversion in... error. How do I handle this?

Comment: Try this:
`$valString = implode( ",", $vals );`

`$resultW = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE * FROM newchk WHERE sbstart IN ({$valString}) AND dist_chk='{$distUsr}'");`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `print_r`, which prints out readable information about a variable, use the `implode` command:

```
echo "Delete following? " . implode(", ",$_POST['del']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Your entire for loop can be replaced by:

```
echo implode(" ", $a);
```